# Closing A Bootstrap Modal Window in Laravel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm getting the Bootstrap modal window to pop up with the stored session data, but I can't close it. I had to add the class "show" to the div in order for it to even appear.

```
 @if (Session::has('message'))
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#confirm').modal('show');

    });

</script>
<div class="modal show" id="confirm"> 
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">   
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4>{{ Session::get('message') }}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>You are now signed up for our newsletter.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Is your problem the fact that it shows on every request or that you need to close it programmatically after the page is rendered?

Comment: Close it programmatically after the page is rendered. It only shows if I've entered a valid e-mail and it inserts into the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your modal should display just fine by calling `$('#confirm').modal('show')`, so check your browser console for any javascript errors. As for closing it it's just as easy:

```
$('#confirm').modal('hide');
```

Here's an example that automatically opens it on load and closes it after waiting for 5 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/7wt719p3/1/

#### Edit

Make sure you are loading jQuery before the Bootstrap JS plugins file. Bootstrap needs jQuery for it's plugins (like modal) to work. Here's how to include it using a CDN:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think it has something to do with how the modal is being triggered by the Laravel routing. Right now, in my route, if the email is validated, it's entered into a database and then sets a session variable like so:       
  Subscriber::create(array('email' =>          Input::get('email')));
  return Redirect::to('/')
  ->with('message', 'Thanks for signing up!');
 }                                                                The session variable is set, so it loads the modal window, but it only shows if I include the class "show".

Comment: I understand, but as you can see from my purely HTML/JS example, it should work, and the fact that it's not showing using the JavaScript trigger, has nothing to do with Laravel. The `show` class you're adding is just a CSS helper which forces the modal to display without any JS trigger. Have you checked your browser console for JavaScript errors?

Comment: There is a Javascript error. It's saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (index):41(anonymous function) Line 41 references the opening script tag. @if (Session::has('message'))

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#confirm').modal('show');

    });
    </script>

Comment: The Bootstrap plugins need jQuery to work and that error confirms that you aren't loading jQuery or that it's not being loaded correctly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hm, it's still giving the JS error. I switched to the CDN instead of the local folder, but the box isn't showing.

Comment: Are you including jQuery and Bootstrap before the JS code that opens the modal?

Comment: Moving the jQuery and Bootstrap to the head fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your html structure

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h3>Modal Body</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To show :

```
$('#basicModal').modal({'show':true});
```

To hide

```
$('#basicModal').modal({'show':false});
```